# Where are context menu actions registered in the registry?

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, context-menu

I'm using `WinMerge` and would like to change it's context menu title from `Compare` to `&Compare` (So I can use the <kbd>AppsKey</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd> combination to compare files easily.

Can I do it? Or do I need to re-write the application itself to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The context menus for `WinMerge` are dynamic and cannot be changed in the registry - they are defined within the `Shell Extension` DLL. (it is most likely that most/all applications are like that.

I opened the `c:\Program Files\WinMerge\ShellExtensionU.dll` file using one of `Total Commander`'s plug-ins (I don't know which). Then navigated to .`RT_STRING\1033\7.rc` which is the **English** language text for the context menu. 
Then I changed it from:

```
STRINGTABLE
LANGUAGE 9, 1
BEGIN
  100, "ShellExtension"
  101, "WinMerge"
  102, "Open with WinMerge"
  103, "Please select no more than 2 items"
  104, "Compare"
  105, "Compare..."
  106, "Compare To"
  107, "Save this path. Select another path to compare with this path."
  109, "Compare to saved path (%1)"
  110, "Re-select First"
END
```

To:

```
STRINGTABLE
LANGUAGE 9, 1
BEGIN
  100, "ShellExtension"
  101, "WinMerge"
  102, "Open with WinMerge"
  103, "Please select no more than 2 items"
  104, "&Compare"
  105, "Compare..."
  106, "&Compare To"
  107, "Save this path. Select another path to compare with this path."
  109, "Compare to saved path (%1)"
  110, "Re-select First"
END
```

After a re-start, the context menus were updated.

Answer (score 1):

The handlers for shell extensions that I have are here. Probably a good place to start.

```
HKCU\Software\Classes\*\ShellEx\ContextMenuHandlers         

HKCU\Software\Classes\Directory\ShellEx\ContextMenuHandlers     

HKLM\Software\Classes\*\ShellEx\ContextMenuHandlers 

HKLM\Software\Classes\Directory\ShellEx\ContextMenuHandlers
```

Comment: Thanks - that answered the 1st part of my question and helped me in my investigation. But the answer was within the application itself :)