# How can I invoke context menu actions with a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, context-menu

On Windows, I'd like to set up a hotkey for an action in my context menu, much the same way `enter` invokes "Open" for folders and files by default and `F2` invokes rename.

The actions I'd like to hotkey are not windows defaults.  I'm currently poking around the locations suggested in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/290501/where-are-context-menu-actions-registered-in-the-registry), and I see most of the contexts that I'm looking for, but I'm not sure how to register hotkeys.

My gut tells me I'd need to write a persistently-running script with a tool like AHK to register the hotkey, which when pressed would fetch available context options for the selected file and invoke one based on the hotkey pressed... but I'm not sure how to do that, either.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any programs that does this but by default the items when your right click should have a line under a letter which should be you're shortcut. If its not there you could use autoit to code a way to do it.

This page may be useful to you : http://alanmiller.awardspace.com/context2.htm

But you could also go in the autoiT forum and ask the question there, you'll get help for sure.